# Faster Method for deleting multiple worksheets

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have a workbook with multiple worksheets, most of which are to be deleted every time I run a specific macro. The number of worksheets to be deleted varies anywhere from 1 to 150.

Currently the section of the macro below takes approximately 215 seconds to delete 78 worksheets. Is there any way to make it faster? Less than 60s runtime for a similar number of worksheets?

Here is the relevant section of code:

```
For Each WrkSh In MainFile.Worksheets
  If WrkSh.Index > 5 Then
    WrkSh.Delete
  End If
Next WrkSh


MainFile.Sheets("Input").Unprotect
MainFile.Sheets("Buyers").Unprotect
MainFile.Sheets("Template").Visible = True
MainFile.Sheets("Holidays").Visible = True


With MainFile.Sheets("Input")
  .Range("A10:A200").ClearContents
  .Range("E11:N200").Clear
End With

With MainFile.Sheets("Buyers")
  .Range("A10:B40").ClearContents
  .Range("C11:J40").Clear
End With
```

EDIT: I have this `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at the beginning of the main code.

Comment: Have you tried setting calculation to manual before you delete the sheets, then reset afterwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OPTION 1
You can group the sheets and delete them as a group. That may be faster; you can test it.

```
Dim arrDelete() As String
ReDim arrDelete(MainFile.Worksheets.Count)

Dim index As Long
For Each WrkSh In MainFile.Worksheets
    If WrkSh.index > 5 Then
        arrDelete(index) = WrkSh.Name
        index = index + 1
    End If
Next WrkSh

ReDim Preserve arrDelete(index - 1)

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
MainFile.Sheets(arrDelete).Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

OPTION 2
If there are no links outside of the sheets you want to keep, you could copy those sheets to a new workbook and delete the old workbook. This is probably not the safest option but may work in some situations.

Comment: Thanks. The array method shortened runtime to 4 seconds on average.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`?

Comment: Yes, I am. Including `.DisplayAlerts = False`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's that portion of your code causing the problem? I quickly recreated your situation, and it runs almost instantly.

Comment: I split the code into sections using timers to find out which actions were taking up so much time. Also, previously I'd force a break if it was running too slow and `Wrksh.Delete` would be highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub test()
    Dim a(), sh As Worksheet

    ReDim a(1 To Sheets.Count - 5)
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If sh.Index > 5 Then a(sh.Index - 5) = sh.Name
    Next sh

    Sheets(a).Delete
End Sub
```